# Write output of nested for loop to .csv file

Tags: csv, for-loop

I have a nested for loop that produces a sequence of numbers that I need written to a .csv file, under the column name 'position' (each number in a new row). Below is the nested for-loop.

```
for i in range(140):
    for j in range(21):
        print(i+1)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['position']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for i in range(140):
        for j in range(21):
            writer.writerow({'position': i + 1})
```